# Tensorflow object detection api get labels in array

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to get labels from Tensorflow object detection api and put them into array instead of showing them on the video

this is detect_object function

```
def detect_objects(image_np, sess, detection_graph):
# Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

# Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

# Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
# Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

# Actual detection.
(boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
    [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

# Visualization of the results of a detection.
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image_np,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=8)


return image_np
```

Answer (score 3):

After some research this is what i came up with

```
final_score = np.squeeze(scores)    
    count = 0
    for i in range(100):
        if scores is None or final_score[i] > 0.5:
                count = count + 1
    print('cpunt',count)
    printcount =0;
    for i in classes[0]:
          printcount = printcount +1
          print(category_index[i]['name'])

          if(printcount == count):
                break
```

this will print all the detected objects , if you want to return it u can add it to  some variable and return.

if you only want to print the detected objects add print(class_name) in the visualization_utils.py file inside the util folder

```
if not agnostic_mode:
          if classes[i] in category_index.keys():
            class_name = category_index[classes[i]]['name']

            **print(class_name)** --> this line 
          else:
```

Comment: got `TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable` error with your code

Answer (score 1):

```
    classes=output_dict['detection_classes']
    boxes =output_dict['detection_boxes']
    scores = output_dict['detection_scores']

    for i in range(min(max_boxes_to_draw, boxes.shape[0])):
          if scores is None or scores[i] > min_score_thresh :
              if classes[i] in category_index.keys():
                  class_name = category_index[classes[i]]['name']
                  print(class_name)
```

When i gave max_boxes_to_draw=20 min_score_thresh=0.5 (these are default), it worked.

You can find this piece of code in visualization_utils.py file.

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone who did not get the exact label by following the above 2 answers**

Well I tried each of the above two answers, but it did not gave the exact label. So what I did was to copy and paste the whole code from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py

After copying all the code to my jupyter notebook, I changed some part of the original code. It was to return the detected label along with `image` array inside the `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array()` function

So, part of the code for `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array()` function should look like this:

```py
def visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    boxes,
    classes,
    scores,
    category_index,
    instance_masks=None,
    instance_boundaries=None,
    keypoints=None,
    keypoint_scores=None,
    keypoint_edges=None,
    track_ids=None,
    use_normalized_coordinates=False,
    max_boxes_to_draw=20,
    min_score_thresh=.5,
    agnostic_mode=False,
    line_thickness=4,
    mask_alpha=.4,
    groundtruth_box_visualization_color='black',
    skip_boxes=False,
    skip_scores=False,
    skip_labels=False,
    skip_track_ids=False):
  """Overlay labeled boxes on an image with formatted scores and label names.
  This function groups boxes that correspond to the same location
  and creates a display string for each detection and overlays these
  on the image. Note that this function modifies the image in place, and returns
  that same image.
  Args:
    image: uint8 numpy array with shape (img_height, img_width, 3)
    boxes: a numpy array of shape [N, 4]
    classes: a numpy array of shape [N]. Note that class indices are 1-based,
      and match the keys in the label map.
    scores: a numpy array of shape [N] or None.  If scores=None, then
      this function assumes that the boxes to be plotted are groundtruth
      boxes and plot all boxes as black with no classes or scores.
    category_index: a dict containing category dictionaries (each holding
      category index `id` and category name `name`) keyed by category indices.
    instance_masks: a uint8 numpy array of shape [N, image_height, image_width],
      can be None.
    instance_boundaries: a numpy array of shape [N, image_height, image_width]
      with values ranging between 0 and 1, can be None.
    keypoints: a numpy array of shape [N, num_keypoints, 2], can
      be None.
    keypoint_scores: a numpy array of shape [N, num_keypoints], can be None.
    keypoint_edges: A list of tuples with keypoint indices that specify which
      keypoints should be connected by an edge, e.g. [(0, 1), (2, 4)] draws
      edges from keypoint 0 to 1 and from keypoint 2 to 4.
    track_ids: a numpy array of shape [N] with unique track ids. If provided,
      color-coding of boxes will be determined by these ids, and not the class
      indices.
    use_normalized_coordinates: whether boxes is to be interpreted as
      normalized coordinates or not.
    max_boxes_to_draw: maximum number of boxes to visualize.  If None, draw
      all boxes.
    min_score_thresh: minimum score threshold for a box or keypoint to be
      visualized.
    agnostic_mode: boolean (default: False) controlling whether to evaluate in
      class-agnostic mode or not.  This mode will display scores but ignore
      classes.
    line_thickness: integer (default: 4) controlling line width of the boxes.
    mask_alpha: transparency value between 0 and 1 (default: 0.4).
    groundtruth_box_visualization_color: box color for visualizing groundtruth
      boxes
    skip_boxes: whether to skip the drawing of bounding boxes.
    skip_scores: whether to skip score when drawing a single detection
    skip_labels: whether to skip label when drawing a single detection
    skip_track_ids: whether to skip track id when drawing a single detection
  Returns:
    uint8 numpy array with shape (img_height, img_width, 3) with overlaid boxes.
  """
  # Create a display string (and color) for every box location, group any boxes
  # that correspond to the same location.
  box_to_display_str_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
  box_to_color_map = collections.defaultdict(str)
  box_to_instance_masks_map = {}
  box_to_instance_boundaries_map = {}
  box_to_keypoints_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
  box_to_keypoint_scores_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
  box_to_track_ids_map = {}
  final_labels = []
  if not max_boxes_to_draw:
    max_boxes_to_draw = boxes.shape[0]
  for i in range(boxes.shape[0]):
    if max_boxes_to_draw == len(box_to_color_map):
      break
    if scores is None or scores[i] > min_score_thresh:
      box = tuple(boxes[i].tolist())
      if instance_masks is not None:
        box_to_instance_masks_map[box] = instance_masks[i]
      if instance_boundaries is not None:
        box_to_instance_boundaries_map[box] = instance_boundaries[i]
      if keypoints is not None:
        box_to_keypoints_map[box].extend(keypoints[i])
      if keypoint_scores is not None:
        box_to_keypoint_scores_map[box].extend(keypoint_scores[i])
      if track_ids is not None:
        box_to_track_ids_map[box] = track_ids[i]
      if scores is None:
        box_to_color_map[box] = groundtruth_box_visualization_color
      else:
        display_str = ''
        if not skip_labels:
          if not agnostic_mode:
            if classes[i] in six.viewkeys(category_index):
              class_name = category_index[classes[i]]['name']
            else:
              class_name = 'N/A'
            display_str = str(class_name)
            
        final_label = display_str
        final_labels.append(final_label)

        if not skip_scores:
          if not display_str:
            display_str = '{}%'.format(round(100*scores[i]))
            final_label = display_str
          else:
            display_str = '{}: {}%'.format(display_str, round(100*scores[i]))
        if not skip_track_ids and track_ids is not None:
          if not display_str:
            display_str = 'ID {}'.format(track_ids[i])
            final_label = track_ids[i]
          else:
            display_str = '{}: ID {}'.format(display_str, track_ids[i])
        
        box_to_display_str_map[box].append(display_str)
        if agnostic_mode:
          box_to_color_map[box] = 'DarkOrange'
        elif track_ids is not None:
          prime_multipler = _get_multiplier_for_color_randomness()
          box_to_color_map[box] = STANDARD_COLORS[
              (prime_multipler * track_ids[i]) % len(STANDARD_COLORS)]
        else:
          box_to_color_map[box] = STANDARD_COLORS[
              classes[i] % len(STANDARD_COLORS)]

  # Draw all boxes onto image.
  for box, color in box_to_color_map.items():
    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box
    if instance_masks is not None:
      draw_mask_on_image_array(
          image,
          box_to_instance_masks_map[box],
          color=color,
          alpha=mask_alpha
      )
    if instance_boundaries is not None:
      draw_mask_on_image_array(
          image,
          box_to_instance_boundaries_map[box],
          color='red',
          alpha=1.0
      )
    draw_bounding_box_on_image_array(
        image,
        ymin,
        xmin,
        ymax,
        xmax,
        color=color,
        thickness=0 if skip_boxes else line_thickness,
        display_str_list=box_to_display_str_map[box],
        use_normalized_coordinates=use_normalized_coordinates)
    if keypoints is not None:
      keypoint_scores_for_box = None
      if box_to_keypoint_scores_map:
        keypoint_scores_for_box = box_to_keypoint_scores_map[box]
      draw_keypoints_on_image_array(
          image,
          box_to_keypoints_map[box],
          keypoint_scores_for_box,
          min_score_thresh=min_score_thresh,
          color=color,
          radius=line_thickness / 2,
          use_normalized_coordinates=use_normalized_coordinates,
          keypoint_edges=keypoint_edges,
          keypoint_edge_color=color,
          keypoint_edge_width=line_thickness // 2)

  return final_labels, image
```

Here, I have just created a variable called `final_label` which is the class name of the detected bounding box.

While calling this function, you have to use this code:

```py
labels, image = visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np_with_detections, #change this according to your image array name
            detections['detection_boxes'],
            detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
            detections['detection_scores'],
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            max_boxes_to_draw=8,
            min_score_thresh=.50,
            agnostic_mode=False)

print(labels)
```

It will surely give the exact label detected :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It sucks we need to do this but it works.
I made one modification for my own purposes and converted `final_label` into a list called `final_labels` and appended them into it... This way if there are multiple labels, you get them.

Comment: @robinwkurtz, you can update my answer if your modification is more helpful